# Can I use component's property as method's argument in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 6 application I have method which should modify my component's property. What I exactly mean:

```
...
value: number = 10;
changeValue(v) { return v = 100; }
...
```

The I invoke this method with component's property:

```
this.changeValue(this.value); // didn't modify this.value
```

and I expect that `this.value` will be equal to 100, but it's still equals to 10. At the same time, I know that I can read value of `v` parameter (`this.value` in my case) inside of the function, but I can't modify it.

What I'm doing wrong and how can I achieve desired behavior?
Could you show me right direction to solve this problem, please?
I'll be appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Typescript, primitives (string, number, boolean etc) are passed by value. So, you can do (at least) two things

You can assign the return value of the method to the `value` variable

```
changeValue(){
   return 100;
}

this.value = this.changeValue();
```

Or you can do:

```
changeValue(){
   this.value = 100;
}

this.changeValue();
```

**UPDATE**

As [Jeto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965834/jeto) mentioned in the comment, even if you passed an object instead of a primitive, the result would not change since you are assigning to object itself but not the object's property.

```
value = {foo: 'bar'}

changeValue(v){
    return v = {foo: 'baz'};
}

console.log(this.value); // {foo: 'bar'}
this.changeValue(this.value);
console.log(this.value); // {foo: 'bar'}  #Unchanged
```

But if you want to change its property instead object itself, it will work

```
value = {foo: 'bar'}

changeValue(v){
    v.foo = 'baz'
}

console.log(this.value); // {foo: 'bar'}
this.changeValue(this.value);
console.log(this.value); // {foo: 'baz'}  #Changed
```

Comment: Note that even if an object was being passed (by reference), it would've not changed anything in the current case since OP's using `=` (the assignment operator).

Comment: You are completely right. OP asked for changing a primitive, therefore I answered this way. But thanks for clarification anyway. Updating the answer to give this detail.